# put child at center of parent element

Tags: html, css, center

If you look at [Yahoo!](http://yahoo.com) home page, you find all content centered in page and if you resize browser window, left and right space will be removed and then scroll bar will appear. I want the same but whatever I do, I can not do that:

```
<body>
<div id="main" >
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="copyright"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want `main` to be at center of page( width is fixed but margin is not).

Comment: sorry about that I decided just to answer your question this may be a repeat question.

Comment: @RichardAndrewLee  I read all suggestion that SO showed me!If there was any, I wouldn't bother myself posting question. btw, thanks for answer, it works;)

Comment: sweet: http://jsfiddle.net/tszxg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In css set it up like this.

```
#main {
   width: 960px;/*put your width*/
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: `position: relative;` is **not** necessary.  Also, check spelling.

Comment: You're right I just got in the habit of putting that on my body. (sorry about that)

Answer (score 1):

1st way:

```
#main {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-300px;
}
```

- [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yumYB/1/)

2nd way:

```
body {
  text-align:center; /* Optional: IE5/6 Quirks Mode Hack */
}

#main {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:left; /* Optional: IE5/6 Quirks Mode Hack */
}​
```

- [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yumYB/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Note: this css doesn't work in IE. Solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{text-align: center}

</style>
```

from: http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/IE7-margin-auto-not-working/